# What is the purpose of hweight macros in the linux kernel?

Tags: linux-kernel

I came across the `hweight8`/`hweight16`/`hweight32`/... macros when reading through some driver code in the kernel. I would like to understand, what these macros are for and what they are doing but unfortunately I failed to find any documentation on the topic.

The definition of the macros looks like this and can be found in
[include/asm-generic/bitops/const_hweight.h](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v5.18/include/asm-generic/bitops/const_hweight.h)

```
#define hweight8(w)  (__builtin_constant_p(w) ? __const_hweight8(w)  : __arch_hweight8(w))
#define hweight16(w) (__builtin_constant_p(w) ? __const_hweight16(w) : __arch_hweight16(w))
#define hweight32(w) (__builtin_constant_p(w) ? __const_hweight32(w) : __arch_hweight32(w))
#define hweight64(w) (__builtin_constant_p(w) ? __const_hweight64(w) : __arch_hweight64(w))
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, found the answer!

The hweight functions seem to be used for counting the number of bits equals 1  in a byte/word. I do not fully understand the use case but I have found [this piece of code](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/4b0986a3613c92f4ec1bdc7f60ec66fea135991f/drivers/mtd/nand/raw/nand_base.c#L2677) in the Linux NAND driver using it for checking if a block is erased (all bits are 1) while accepting some bits to be flipped.

Example calls:

```
hweight8(1)  --> 1
hweight8(2)  --> 1
hweight8(3)  --> 2
hweight8(4)  --> 1
hweight8(5)  --> 2
hweight8(6)  --> 2
hweight8(7)  --> 3
hweight8(8)  --> 1
and so on...
```

Comment: If you are wondering about the names, they are short for "Hamming weight".

Comment: and they are used by the perf code